# Best demo apps for Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, web-component

Does Google plan to open source an app like Google I/O Web Application (IOWA) mentioned in I/O 2015 Polymer session to demonstrate best practices?

I think that providing valuable insights into a very sophisticated app like IOWA would immensely benefit the Polymer 1.0 adopters.

Also, are there plans to update Polymer gmail i.e. https://github.com/ebidel/polymer-gmail to 1.0?

Thanks.

Comment: Here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/ioweb2015

Comment: Alternatively, since Polymer is completely client-side you could also view-source on something like the Google Music Player or Youtube web pages.  Not as effective as an open source demo application, but there's likely to be some insightful examples there.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Thad: Is there a demo page or something for that [ioweb2015 Git](http://github.com/GoogleChrome/ioweb2015)?

Comment: @Mowzer Maybe someone has put it up somewhere. I cloned and ran it once.

Answer (score 0):

[You might be looking for this](http://polymerlabs.github.io/app-layout/). It's **App Layout** — *A collection of elements, along with guidelines and templates that can be used to structure your app’s layout.*

That link was taken from the first resource at [the end of the video shown here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiiXKoLYLMo&t=31m49s) — which, itself, is an excellent resource.